# Redis lost data upon unexpected termination

Tags: javascript, redis, screen

I had set up a server for the collaborative editing program ethercalc, which uses redis. Everything was going fine until yesterday, when the server went down. I ssh'd into the server (Ubuntu 12.04.3) and found that the screen processes that I had been running (one for ethercalc, and one for redis) had both been terminated. I'm not sure as to why that had happened.

When I started them back up, I found that the spreadsheets that I had previously edited were entirely gone. Redis's dump.rdb file was only about a kilobyte in size. What could have happened, can I fix it and how can I stop it from happening again?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that there is any way in which you can recover your lost data now but for future it is a good idea to create multiple instances of Redis and declare one as master and others as their slave. The application only needs to interact with the master, Redis does a pretty good job of asynchronous replication of data among the slaves.

In a scenario, where you loose your master Redis node you can upgrade one of the slaves as the master with minimal loss of data. Starting from Redis 2.8, a master-master replication is also supported.

[Redis replication documentation](http://redis.io/topics/replication) gives a detailed explanation.

Comment: chetanme, you mention master-master replication. I didn't know about that, interesting. However, I can't find any info on that at the link you posted. Where did you read this? You aren't talking about Redis Cluster, which is still in beta?

Comment: Yes. Clustering is being talked about since 2.6, it was removed again from 2.8 I think. I hope it comes out in the next stable release.